# Topological "Freshman's Dream"

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, quotient-spaces

When one learns about quotient and product spaces in topology for the first time, it is perhaps natural to expect that they would behave like mutual inverses:

> *Topological Freshman's Dream (TFD).* For a space $X$ and subspace $\emptyset \neq Y\subseteq X$, the spaces $(X/Y)\times Y$ and $X$ are homeomorphic.

It is not too hard to see that TFD is not true even for very simple spaces. For example, pick $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$, then $X/Y\times Y$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $S^1$, obviously not the same as $X$.

There are two trivial cases when TFD does hold, when $Y$ is a single point and when $Y$ is the whole space $X$.

> *Q.* Is there any **nontrivial** example when TFD **holds**?

I've tried for a while to construct such an example without success.

---

Some incomplete observations:

- If $X$ is connected, then $Y$ must be as well. Otherwise, $(X/Y)\times Y$ would be disconnected.
- We can apply the tools of algebraic topology to see, for example, that TFD implies $\pi_n(X)\cong\pi_n(X/Y)\times\pi_n(Y)$. This condition is quite hard to satisfy since it implies that the homotopy groups of the quotient space $X/Y$ are simpler than that of $X$, which generally fails quite spectatularly. A similar idea can also be applied to the homology and cohomology groups.
- A special case of the above point implies that if $X$ is simply connected, then both $Y$ and $X/Y$ are simply connected (take the fundamental group $\pi_1$).

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: In light of the answers it would be very interesting to see whether there can be any "nice"  (say Hausdorff) *connected* space with this property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many examples where both $X/Y\cong X$ and $X\times Y\cong X$, from which it follows that $X/Y\times Y\cong X$.  Probably the easiest is if $X$ is an infinite discrete space and $Y$ is any nonempty subspace of $X$ such that $|X\setminus Y|=|X|$.  For a less trivial example, you could take $X=\mathbb{Q}$ or $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $Y$ any nonempty finite subset of $X$ (for these it takes some work to show that $X/Y\cong X$).

Here's a nontrivial example along these lines where $X$ is a CW complex.  Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the union of all the circles of radius $1$ centered at points of the form $(2a,3b)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  This is a disjoint union of infinitely many infinite "chains of circles" attached at single points.  Let $Y=\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$.  Then $X/Y\cong X$, since this quotient just takes one of the circles and pinches it together to form two circles (so its chain of circles remains an infinite chain of circles), and $X\times Y\cong X$ since that product just doubles the already infinite number of chains of circles in $X$.

Comment: $\Bbb Q{/}\Bbb Z$ is not even metrisable. Nor is $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}{/}Y$ for many $Y$.

Comment: I require $Y$ to be finite in those examples, though.

Comment: I think discrete and indiscrete are the only easy options.

Comment: He wants it to hold for *all* subspaces $Y$.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question which indicates that.  (That would be an interesting different question though!  Though, you need to at least require $Y$ to be nonempty to have any hope.)

Comment: The first paragraph formulates the TFD as such. An example of TFD is where this holds for some $X$ and all non-empty subspaces $Y$.

Comment: Nothing in the phrasing says that it has to hold for fixed $X$ but all $Y$.  Indeed, the "trivial examples" given later suggest exactly the opposite, since they involve a specific choice of $Y$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both of your responses and the discussion in the comments! My original intention was indeed to allow a specific choice of $Y$, not for it to hold for all nonempty subspaces $Y$ in fixed $X$. Sorry if the phrasing was unclear! :)

Comment: @tomasz no, it’s not a group quotient but a subset identification. It’s not first countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Ah, *this* $\mathbf Q/{\mathbf Z}$.

Answer (score 8):

A potential class of examples: If $X$ is infinite discrete, say $|X| = \kappa \ge \aleph_0$.

Then any subspace $Y$ is also discrete and so is $X{/}Y$. A product of two discrete spaces is also discrete so it comes down to sizes, as discrete spaces are homeomorphic iff they have the same cardinality:

If $Y$ is finite, TFD holds as $X{/}Y$ has the same size as $X$ and $|X| = |X| \times n$ for $\kappa$ infinite and $n$ finite.

If $\lambda:=|Y| < |X|$ and is also infinite then $|X{/}Y| = \kappa$ still and indeed $\kappa \times \lambda = \kappa$ so TFD holds.

If $|Y| = |X|$ there are some cases depending on $|X\setminus Y|$, check it out.

Another potential class: indiscrete spaces, as all subspaces and quotients by subspaces are indiscrete and homeomorphism just depends on size.

Comment: If $X$ is discrete of size 4 and we identify a two point set $Y$ then $X{/}Y$ is discrete of size $3$ and as $3 \times 2 \neq 4$ we don't have the isomorphism. So finite ones must be excluded.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a *connected compact Hausdorff* space with this property: the [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube) $X:=[0,1]^\omega$. We can choose $Y:=\{x\in [0,1]^\omega\mid x_1=0\}\subset X$.

Admittably, this is still an "Eric Wofsey type example": it satisfies $X/Y\cong X$ and $X\times Y\cong X$, and now I wonder whether there are example that satisfy neither.

---

**Proving $X/Y\cong X$**

The Hilbert cube can be identified with the following convex compact subset of $ \ell^2$:

$$X:=[0,1]\times[0,1/2]\times[0,1/3]\times\cdots.$$

I believe that the quotient $X/Y$ is homeomorphic to the following subset of $X$:

$$X/Y\cong \Big\{x\in X \;\Big\vert\; x_i\le \frac{x_1}i\text{ for all $i\ge 2$}\Big\}.$$

I furthermore believe that this is still a convex compact subset of $\ell^2$ of infinite dimension. Wikipedia state that every infinite-dimensional convex compact subset of $\ell^2$ is homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube.

Comment: Is there any easy proof that $X/Y\cong X$ in this case?  I believe it should be true but it looks messy to write down a homeomorphism.

Comment: @EricWofsey I admit I believed this to be easier. I had to change the definition of $Y$, but I added some sketch for how I believe one can show $X/Y\cong X$. There are still a lot of "believes" in there, and I make use of a claim from Wikipedia.